# How to run testify setup/teardown with table tests using stretchr/testify in golang?

Tags: go, testify

I'm using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) for testing. I've set up a [suite](https://github.com/stretchr/testify#suite-package) for my tests. However, I'm having trouble using the set up and tear down features when using table tests. Is this by design?

```
package workflows

import (
    "testing"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/suite"
)

type UnitTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func (s *UnitTestSuite) SetupTest() {
    log.Info("setup")
}

func (s *UnitTestSuite) BeforeTest(suiteName, testName string) {
    log.Info("before test")
}

func (s *UnitTestSuite) AfterTest(suiteName, testName string) {
    log.Info("After test")
}


func (s *UnitTestSuite) Test_TableTest() {

    type testCase struct {
        name string
    }

    testCases := []testCase{
        {
            name: "1",
        },
        {
            name: "2",
        },
    }

    for _, testCase := range testCases {

        s.Run(testCase.name, func() {
            // logic ...
            // NOTE that the SetupTest and BeforeTest do not get called for each test here
        })
    }
}

func TestUnitTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(UnitTestSuite))
}
```

When I run the `TestUnitTestSuite` I get the following output:

```
=== RUN   TestUnitTestSuite
--- PASS: TestUnitTestSuite (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest
time="2021-04-17T07:49:28-04:00" level=info msg=setup
time="2021-04-17T07:49:28-04:00" level=info msg="before test"
    --- PASS: TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest/1
        --- PASS: TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest/1 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest/2
time="2021-04-17T07:49:28-04:00" level=info msg="After test"
        --- PASS: TestUnitTestSuite/Test_TableTest/2 (0.00s)
PASS
```

Note that `setup` and `before test` appear only once in the output even though there are two tests being run.

Is there a way for me to automatically run `SetupTest` (or some alternative) prior to each of my table tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of how testify works. The Setup/Before/After are called for the TestSuite rather than per subtest (table test case). There is a [Github issue here](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/1031).

You can just call `s.SetupTest()` within the loop before you do the actual test.